# Getting values from multiple textboxes in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have the following code.

```
from Tkinter import  *

root = Tk()
n_array = []        #will be used as 2d array

def add_four_entries():
    global root, n_array

    row_array=[]    #array used to store a row
    n_array.append(row_array)
    y=len(n_array)            

    for x in range(4):
        tbn="t"+str(y)+str(x)   #create entrybox names of the form t10, t11,...
        #print(tbn)
        tbn=Entry(root)
        row_array.append(tbn)
        row_array[x].grid(row=y, column=x,sticky="nsew", padx=2,pady=2)

def getval():
    for row in range(len(n_array)):

        for col in range(4):
            tbn="t"+str(row+1)+str(col)
            print(tbn.get())

Button(root, text="Add new row", command=add_four_entries).grid(row=0, column=1,)
Button(root, text="Print val", command=getval).grid(row=21, column=1,)
mainloop()
```

The button 'add new row' creates a row of four text boxes, each time it is pressed. The button 'Print Val' prints the values of all text boxes one by one.
Since the text boxes are dynamically named, the names are string type. But ob clicking the get Val button I am getting this error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
for col in range(4):
    tbn="t"+str(row+1)+str(col)
    print(tbn.get())
```

with

```
for col in range(4):
    print(n_array[row][col].get())
```

You don't need to store names. If the grid is built in a known order you can use the n_array indexes (actually a list of lists) as coordinates to get to the `Entry` controls you saved.

You are actually throwing away the `tbn` strings when you do

```
tbn=Entry(root)
```

but you store the Entry objects, that's why it still works.